# How can I use plinq to fill an array with strings returned from my "FormatStatus" Method?

Tags: c#, linq, plinq

This is my first time playing around with linq and I can't quite figure out what I need to search on google to find out what I am doing wrong, so here I am.
Here is what I have so far:

```
var formattedStatuses =
            (from status in _statusCollection
            select FormatStatus(status)).AsParallel();
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var formattedStatus = from status in _statusCollection.AsParallel()
                      select FormatStatus(status);
```

Comment: Also, you could create an extension method on the string class and then 
  select status.Formatted();

Comment: Thank you! The Formatting would still be done on different threads via plinq this way?

Comment: Yes, as far as I understand it.